# How to read a part of a csv file in perl

Tags: perl

I have a CSV file with pattern as follow :

```
start_var1 val1 val2
            abc   12
            xyz   23 
  end_var1  pqr   32

start_var2  val1 val2
            abc1  121
            xyz1  232
  end_var2  pqr1  341
```

I need to save values in different arrays named `var1_arr`, `var2_arr` in the following pattern :

```
val1(val2)
```

It should not save empty rows if there is any in between two rows and each array should have values which is in between `start_var` up to `end_var` respectively.

```
if ( $columns[0] eq "start_var1" .. $columns[0] eq "end_var1") {
      if ( $columns[1] ne "") {
      push @var1_arr , "$columns[1]($columns[3])\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: this code is working for me but the issue is that I dont want it to push start_var* row values in array , how can i skip reading that one line. please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, to skip a line you can write like this:

```
while (my $line = <$fh>)
{
    next if ($line =~ /start_var*/);    
    #do here whatever you want to do

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS). (That's assuming you have a csv file that looks like one, the thing you pasted looks like 2 put together)

```
use strict;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, sep_char => ' '});

open(my $fh, "<", $filename) or die "$! $filename";

my $skip_heading = 1;
my $col1; # rename as appropriate of course
my $col2;
my $col3;
my @var1_arr;
my @var2_arr;
$csv->bind_columns(\$col1, \$col2, \$col3);
while ($csv->getline($fh)) {
    if ($skip_heading == 1) {
        $skip_heading = 0;
        next;
    }

    if ($col2 and $col3) {
        push(@var1_arr, "$col2($col3)\n");
    }
}
```